# Confused about useBuiltIns option of @babel/preset-env (using Browserslist Integration)

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-preset-env

I'm working on a web project using Babel 7 with Webpack 4. I've never used Babel before and can't really understand some parts of it. Based on the [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env) I'm using `@babel/preset-env` because it seems the recommended way (especially for beginners). Also using Browserslist integration via my `.browserslistrc` file.

Webpack does the compilation well (`babel-loader` version `8.0.2`), I have no errors but I'm confused about this `useBuiltIns: "entry"` [option mentioned here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#browserslist-integration) and how `polyfill` system is working in Babel.

**.babelrc.js**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', {
      "useBuiltIns": "entry" // do I need this?
    }]
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import'
  ]
};
```

**.browserslistrc**
Copied from [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.1.3/.browserslistrc) (thought reasonable because my project is using Bootstrap).

```
>= 1%
last 1 major version
not dead
Chrome >= 45
Firefox >= 38
Edge >= 12
Explorer >= 10
iOS >= 9
Safari >= 9
Android >= 4.4
Opera >= 30
```

**So my questions are:**

1) Do I need to use that `useBuiltIns: "entry"` option?

2) Do I need to install `@babel/polyfill` package and start my `vendors.js` with `require("@babel/polyfill");` ?

3) What if I omit both?

If I do 1 and 2, my `vendors.js` grows up to `411 KB`
If I ommit both it's just `341 KB`
after a production build.

I thought `@babel/preset-env` handles all the rewrites and polyfills by default without any extra `import/require` needed on my side...

Thanks!

**-- EDIT --**

*Babel's team has just [updated](https://github.com/babel/website/pull/1858) the [docs of `@babel/polyfill`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill#usage-in-node-browserify-webpack) based on some GitHub issues (including mine) complaining about unclear/misleading documentation. Now it's obvious how to use it. (...and after that my original question seems stupid :)*

Answer (score 132, accepted):

> 1) Do I need to use that useBuiltIns: "entry" option?

Yes, if you want to include polyfills based on your target environment.

TL;DR

There're basically 3 options for `useBuiltIns`:

**"entry"**: when using this option, `@babel/preset-env` replaces direct imports of `core-js` to imports of only the specific modules required for a target environment.

That means you need to add

```
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
```

to your entry point and these lines will be replaced by only required polyfills. When targeting chrome 72, it will be transformed by `@babel/preset-env` to

```
import "core-js/modules/es.array.unscopables.flat";
import "core-js/modules/es.array.unscopables.flat-map";
import "core-js/modules/es.object.from-entries";
import "core-js/modules/web.immediate";
```

---

**"usage"**: in this case polyfills will be added automatically when the usage of some feature is unsupported in target environment. So:

```
const set = new Set([1, 2, 3]);
[1, 2, 3].includes(2);
```

in browsers like `ie11` will be replaced with

```
import "core-js/modules/es.array.includes";
import "core-js/modules/es.array.iterator";
import "core-js/modules/es.object.to-string";
import "core-js/modules/es.set";

const set = new Set([1, 2, 3]);
[1, 2, 3].includes(2);
```

In case target browser is latest chrome, no transformations will apply.

That's personally my chosen weapon as there's no need to include anything (core-js or regenerator) in source code as only required polyfills will be added automatically based on target environment set in browserlist.

---

**false**: that's the default value when no polyfills are added automatically.

---

> 2) Do I need to install @babel/polyfill package and start my
>   vendors.js with require("@babel/polyfill"); ?

Yes for environment prior to `babel v7.4` and `core-js v3`.

TL;DR

No. Starting from `babel v7.4` and `core-js v3` (which is used for polyfilling under the hood) `@babel/preset-env` will add the polyfills only when it know which of them required and in the recommended order.

Moreover `@babel/polyfill` is considered as deprecated in favor of separate `core-js` and `regenerator-runtime` inclusions.

So using of `useBuiltIns` with options other than false should solve the issue.

Don't forget to add `core-js` as a dependency to your project and set its version in `@babel/preset-env` under `corejs` property.

---

> 3) What if I omit both?

As @PlayMa256 already answered, there will be no polyfills.

---

More detailed and whole info con be found at `core-js` [creator's page](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/docs/2019-03-19-core-js-3-babel-and-a-look-into-the-future.md#babel)

Also please feel free to play with [babel sandbox](https://github.com/elitvinchuk/babel-sandbox)

Comment: When using "usage" I must use `import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";` ?

Comment: No, you only need to add `core-js` to dependencies

Comment: Good answer. The Babel documentation says: "When either the usage or entry options are used, @babel/preset-env will add direct references to core-js modules as bare imports (or requires). This means core-js will be resolved relative to the file itself and needs to be accessible." is very hard to understand without context or examples.

Comment: This will save people a week: https://github.com/babel/babel/discussions/14443

Answer (score 15):

> 1) Do I need to use that useBuiltIns: "entry" option?

Yes, according to babel docs:

"This option enables a new plugin that replaces the statement import "@babel/polyfill" or require("@babel/polyfill") with individual requires for @babel/polyfill based on environment" - Basically, includes all needed polyfills (when you have `@babel/polyfill` installed when needed).

> 2) Do I need to install @babel/polyfill package and start my vendors.js with require("@babel/polyfill"); ?

You do need to install `@babel/polyfill`, it does not come by default on babel. You have to include that on your entrypoint or add an import at the top of your entrypoint.

> 3) What if I omit both?

You won't have polyfills.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand. Meanwhile I've read the docs of `babel-polyfill` and this part was really useful: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill#size

Comment: Current documentation around this: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill#usage-in-node-browserify-webpack

Comment: The language surrounding this topic is pretty confusing and initially seems to contradict itself...It's not immediately clear that what is meant is that the import "@babel/polyfill" statement IS necessary at the top of your entrypoint, and when useBuiltIns: 'entry' is used, this statement gets AUTOMATICALLY replaced for you to import individual needed polyfills at build time

Comment: Note that if you set `useBuiltIns` to "usage", you don't have to add `@babel/polyfill` to the entry array anymore. https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill#usage-in-node-browserify-webpack