# Migrate from direct import of core-js/regenerator-runtime to a fully "automatic" Babel configuration?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, core-js

Util now, I was using Babel with the following `.babelrc` **configuration file**:

**=========== Solution A ===========**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ]
}
```

And, in my **entrypoint** `app.js` I directly imported:

```
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
```

**=========== Solution B ===========**

Recently I've read about `babel-preset-env` more in deep. Also based [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52625979/confused-about-usebuiltins-option-of-babel-preset-env-using-browserslist-integ#answer-56505264), it's more convenient to set core-js version inside `.babelrc` and set `useBuiltIns: "usage"`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "corejs": 3,
      "useBuiltIns": "usage"
    }]
  ]
}
```

This way, I can't get rid of the imports inside `app.js` because all required polyfill will be automatically included.

**My question is: am I'm doing it correctly? Where to put the `regenerator-runtime` imports?**

With the following `app.js`:

```
console.log(Array.from('foo'));
```

Output of `npx babel src/app.js` with **solution A**:

```
"use strict";

require("core-js/stable");

require("regenerator-runtime/runtime");

console.log(Array.from('foo'));
```

Output of `npx babel src/app.js` with **solution B**:

```
"use strict";

require("core-js/modules/es.array.from");

require("core-js/modules/es.string.iterator");

console.log(Array.from('foo'));
```