# Gulp & Babel polyfill Promises for IE11 issue

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-polyfill, core-js, gulp-babel

I have an old project written in Angular.js. I need to polyfill promises for IE11 but it's not working.

In gulpfile.js I have requires for Babel stuff

```
var corejs = require('core-js/stable'),
    regenerator = require('regenerator-runtime/runtime'),
    presetEnv = require('@babel/preset-env'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    babel = require('gulp-babel'),
    babelRegister = require ('@babel/register'),
```

And here I am using the pipe

```
var envJS = function () {
    var condition = (config[environment].compression);
    return gulp.src(paths.appJS)
        .pipe(babel(
            {
                "presets": [
                    [ "@babel/preset-env", {
                      "targets": {
                          "browsers": ["ie >= 11"]
                      },
                      "useBuiltIns": "entry",
                      "corejs": 3 
                    }]
                  ]
            }
        ))
        .pipe(ngAnnotate())
        //.pipe(gulpif(!condition, jshint()))
        //.pipe(gulpif(!condition, jshint.reporter('default')))
        .pipe(addStream.obj(prepareTemplates()))
        .pipe(configServer())
        .pipe(gulpif(condition, uglify({mangle: true})))
        .pipe(concat(randomNames.js))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(folderDist))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
};
```

The code builds and works on chrome but still have the issue on IE11 which means it's not polyfilling the Promise object.

I am stuck and don't have any ideas what else should I do.

Comment: Same issue here - doing some work on an older project, and have a very similar gulp setup. The output file does replace arrow functions, but does not replace or polyfil Array.prototype.includes

Comment: I could just manually add a polyfil for this one method, but i would expect babel to handle it, and dont want to have to manually patch any other ES2015 methods i add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had good success with [promise-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-polyfill). As long as that loads before your promise-specific code, it should just work. I know that's not babel-specific, but it solved my IE-compatibility woes back when I still had to support IE.

Comment: Not a Babel solution but it worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The easy solution is to simply change `@babel/preset-env` option `useBuiltIns` from `"entry"` to `"usage"`. Plus, you need to make sure your browser target setting is correct. "ie >= 11" is relatively up-to-date and might not need polyfil at all.

As of the "why" part, well, in short

- `useBuiltIns: "usage"` means: automatically import polyfil code in **each file** that needs it
- `useBuiltIns: "entry"` means: check my **entry file only** and see if I **manually import** `"core-js/stable"` and `"regenerator-runtime/runtime"` modules. If I do, fine tune my import to fit the browser target’s need

To sum up, if you’re using `useBuiltIns: "entry"` and forget to manually import `"core-js/stable"` and `"regenerator-runtime/runtime"` in your entry file, you’re fcked. If you config your browser target wrong, you’re fcked too.

These two sources explain in more details:

- https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins-entry
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56505264/3617380